# Preg Match To Get Everything Between Total || and \\n|}

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

So I want to capture everything between `Total ||` and `\\n|}` inside a string. Right now my current code looks like this:

```
preg_match('/(Total ||)(.*?)(\\n)/', $jsonwiki, $competitors);
```

But my regex fails and returns an empty array and I have no idea why?

Comment: wha t have you tried?

Comment: `/(Total ||)(.*?)(\\n)/`

Comment: @Sami ^^ That is a good start. Put that current regex you got into the question([edit] it) and explain where you got stuck? Did you got an error? Also put your regex into https://regex101.com and play a bit with it.

Comment: `(Total \|\|)(.*?)(\\\\n)`

Comment: @Dagon, awesome.correct answer.pls post your answer.cheers.

Comment: @Sami You can even improve your question more by adding a simple input example explain what you get(you did that already) and explain what you expect to get. So a little code snippet with which everyone can recreate your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i dont know regular expressions well, i just added some escaping

```
(Total \|\|)(.*?)(\\\\n)
```

https://regex101.com/r/nF2wU5/1

`|` and `\` escaped as they are used in the regular expression engine to mean particular things, so if you want a literal pipe you need `\|`

Comment: Maybe explain *why* those characters need to be escaped?

Comment: @Rizier123 yes mum.

Comment: Otherwise you're not allowed to play outside today! :P

Comment: @Dagon did you fall off the face of the earth? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There's a reasonable amount of escaping you need for this type of pattern, because [characters like `|`](http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.meta.php) are operators in regex, so by adding a backslash to escape them you tell the regex interpreter that they should be read verbatim; literally.

```
preg_match('/Total \|\|(.*)\\\\n\|}/', $jsonwiki, $competitors);
                 //↑ ↑     ↑↑   ↑ Backslash added
```

[<kbd>Example</kbd>](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/gT2)

Comment: Maybe explain *why* those characters need to be escaped?

Comment: Cheers @Rizier123